# Ionic - Disable - font color

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Ionic elements - how to show the text in normal color when the element is disabled. changing the opacity at the element level works fine but trying to know how we can change it for all elements in disable mode with a single step(globally)

element in disable mode:
[image]

want the element to look like above in disable mode
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want global styles in your app you have the global.scss file (src/global.scss). Those styles are applied everywhere. If you don't want to place your styles in this file, you can make an @import here and load another file.

About the disabled color, without code it's hard to know what is that you show in the capture (inputs?). In any case, css has the selector :disabled for any disabled input, so:

```
input:disabled, textarea:disabled, select:disabled, button:disabled {
   color: gray;
}
```

If you need to override a ionic element style, try using that property preceded by double hyphen:

```
selector-ionic-element {
   --color: gray;
   color: gray;
}
```

The ion-element (like ion-input, ion-select) in the end contains a native element. For example: ion-input contains a normal input. And when ion-input is disabled, the input has the disabled attribute, so you could just do this:

```
ion-input input:disabled {
   --color: gray;
   color: gray;
}
```